# How to apply combination of filters on array of objects in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi Please help me to write a suitable query for my task, I have list of products with different categories and associated attribute and tags. Here is two documents for two categories along with associated attribute list. There could be multiple attributes, just showing one.

```
   {
   "category": "blouses",
   "attributes": [
       {
           "attribute": "women-blouse-neckline",
           "tag": "round-neck"
       }
   ]
}

{
   "category": "dresses",
   "attributes": [
       {
           "attribute": "women-dress-neckline",
           "tag": "v-neck"
       }
   ]
}
```

Now I want to get list of products from both categories which are `dresses` and `blouses`, but along with that a specific case at attribute level is :
Fetch all the products from `dresses` where attribute is `women-dress-neckline` and tag is `v-neck` along with all the products from `blouses` where attribute is `women-blouse-neckline` and tag is `round-neck`.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To query on each key of `"attributes"`, you need to define "attributes" to be of the nested type, and then use a combination of `bool/must` and [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html)

Adding a working example with index mapping, search query and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "category": "dresses"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "attributes.attribute.keyword": "women-dress-neckline"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "attributes.tag.keyword": "v-neck"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "69611494",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 2.0794413,
        "_source": {
          "category": "dresses",
          "attributes": [
            {
              "attribute": "women-dress-neckline",
              "tag": "v-neck"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

You can combine two nested queries as shown below

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "category": "dresses"
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "attributes",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "attributes.attribute.keyword": "women-dress-neckline"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "attributes.tag.keyword": "v-neck"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "category": "blouses"
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "attributes",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "attributes.attribute.keyword": "women-blouse-neckline"
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "attributes.tag.keyword": "round-neck"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Naresh Sharma please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Thanks @escoder, This working partially as per the requirement. This works well for filtering data for one category but not for both. For example:
A = ( "attribute": "women-dress-neckline" and "tag": "v-neck")
B = ( "attribute": "women-blouse-neckline" and "tag": "round-neck")

For individual A or B it works but we need data for A + B.
I tried to add one more nested query for another category as well but that performs Logical AND operation with and returns nothing. I also try to put nested queries in `should` but it given me result that has `square-neck` as a tag.

Comment: @NareshSharma do you need those documents that satisfy both A AND B condition ?

Comment: Yes I need data for both.

Comment: @NareshSharma please go through the updated query, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: This works for this specific scenario, but it fails when we need to add one more filter for women dresses for example in A and B filter requirements if I add one more attribute condition in A like ( ("attribute": "women-dress-neckline" and "tag": "v-neck") and ("attribute": "women-dress-print" and "tag": "solid") ). In this case It does not return any record because we have to repeat the term like:
"term": {"analysis_result.attributes.name.keyword": "solid"}
"term": {"analysis_result.attributes.name.keyword": "v-neck"}